# Seeking help to loop through web pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a web-scraper that scrapes one page of reviews, but i can't seem to make the scraper go to the second web page so that it scrapes up to 10 pages.

I tried making a for loop with the following class i found identifying attributes: class="BVRRSelectedPageNumber":i
and then i looping with i+1

But i can't seem to get the correct code.

I would love to get tips or advice of where i should start with this code, thank you in advance.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import pandas as pd
import csv

def webScraper():
    for page in range(10):
        url = "https://www.marriott.com/hotels/hotel-reviews/amsnt-amsterdam-marriott-hotel"
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        general_data = soup.find_all(class_='bvseo-review')
        i = 1
        first = general_data[i]
        i+=1

        span = []
        description = []
        rating = []
        auteur = []


        for item in general_data:
            span.append(item.find_all('span'))
            description.append(item.find_all('span', attrs={'itemprop':'description'}))
            rating.append(item.find_all('span', attrs={'itemprop':'ratingValue'}))
            auteur.append(item.find_all('span', attrs={'itemprop':'author'}))

        pagereviews = pd.DataFrame({
            "description":description,
            "ratingValue":rating,
            "author":auteur
        })
    return pagereviews
webScraper()
```

The expected result would be to scrape 10 pages of reviews.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question. But there are multiple things that look very buggy at first glance:

1. At first we have the problem that you use the name `page` as loop-variable, but also assign it a value inside the loop. This is bad coding and leads to unexpected behavior.
2. Second there is the obvious problem that the request url is the same in each iteration of the loop. That leads to each iteration being the same and this is most probably one source of your problem.
3. The following construction is useless:

```
i = 1
first = general_data[i]
i+=1
```

Since this is happening in a for-loop, the last line has never any effect, and `i` will evaluate to `1` in `first = general_data[i]`in every single iteration of your `for`–loop. Why don't you just write `first = general_data[1]`? (Most probably you might actually want `first = general_data[0]`!)

4. The value you are returning in the end, `pagereviews` is overwritten in each iteration of the loop. This also makes the whole for-loop useless, because only the value of the last iteration will be returned. You might want to have a look for pandas `DataFraem.append` method ;-)

Comment: First of all, thank you for pointing out the flaws in my current code. I have been trying some new things and forgot to delete the mess it left behind. 

Second, sorry for the request, I'll try to clarify my request as best as i can.

The current code gives me the wanted output, which is one tab of hotel reviews. The problem that i am facing is that every tab on the website contains 7 reviews, so if I want to extract 50 reviews i have to loop through the tabs on the website. 

I hope this clarifies my earlier request.

Comment: @Pythonamateur If you do not show us the code you are actually using, we cannot help you improving / fixing your code :-) Please edit your question to make it reflect your actual code.